# How to detect in selenium whether loading of a javascript file is loaded via ajax?

Tags: ajax, selenium

My main page loading another page via ajax. Which has javascript file. How do i detect whether that ajax page loading is completed in selenium ? I can check for element loaded. But there are links which are not clickable till that javascript file in inner page is loaded completely. How do i make sure those links are not clickable ?

Because otherwise click event is failing. Though element is present But its not clickable.
Its sumple anchor like  Link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inbuilt mechanism in selenium to detect ajax requests. 
Selenium 2 has this in road map.
Add `waitForcondition` in selenium.

```
selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().$.active== 0
```

NOTE: This works if your page uses jquery. For other frameworks..there are different ways replace $.active with something else.

Comment: I think this only works for the IDE.  To get this to work elsewhere try this: 'selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0'

Comment: Is the browserbot object part of the c# web driver?