# Detecting selenium commands

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation

Is there anyway I can detect selenium commands so I can't automatically insert a screenshot command after each one? I would like to keep this in Javascript as I am using the html testscripts. Example:

`clickandwait | element |`    <-- is there a way to know via Javascript that this was fired so I add

`captureentirepagescreenshot | c:\screenshots.jpg |`     after it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to take screenshots only if a prticular element is present on page? If yes, then in Selenium-RC the code will be

```
if(selenium.isElementPresent("yourElement")){
selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot("c:\screenshots.jpg", "") }
```

You can try `isElementPresent` in Selenium-IDE. I haven't tried this one though, so not sure about it.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. What Im looking for is to take a screenshot at each page load. is this possible. How to detect a page load

Comment: @user516755 - You can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305118/how-to-detect-in-selenium-whether-loading-of-a-javascript-file-is-loaded-via-ajax), I haven't tried it hough.